# Two graph specifications that I expect to produce identical graphs don't

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I would like to add up the following two seemingly identical graphs, but it seems they are different. I can't figure out what is the difference between them and how to make them really identical

```
Graph[
  List[X, x14, x17, Y], 
  List[
    UndirectedEdge[X, x14], UndirectedEdge[x14, x17], UndirectedEdge[x14, x17], 
    UndirectedEdge[x17, x14], UndirectedEdge[x17, Y]]]
```

and

```
Graph[
  List[X, x14, x17, Y], 
  List[
    UndirectedEdge[X, x14], UndirectedEdge[x17, x14], UndirectedEdge[x17, Y], 
    UndirectedEdge[x14, x17], UndirectedEdge[x14, x17]]]
```

The order in which the vertices of the undirected edges is different in the two graphs, but should this make a problem for graphs with undirected edges?

Comment: Sorting the edges will make them identical: `Graph[List[X, x14, x17, Y], Sort@List[ ... ]]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! It works!

Comment: Please don't use full form for no reason (List vs { ... }). It makes things hard to read.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking. Show a concrete example: "this is what I did, this is what happened, this is what I expected to happen instead". I don't understand what it means to "add up graphs" and this sentence is mangled: "order in which the vertices of the undirected edges"

Comment: Dear @Szabolcs, thank very much for your attention. Sorry for confused question, still I'm learning how to post a question correctly. My problem was solved by the help of Bob. In fact, these two graphs are a part of many graphs and there are representing a physical process. Some of them are equivalent and can be "sum up". By Sort I could discover the equivalent graphs.